# torch.utils.save_image is difference in PyTorch 1.7.1 and 1.9.1

Tags: python, pytorch

When I want to save the generated segmentation mask using the function `save_image`. The segmentation size is (4x256x256) have stacked. The save code is

```
save_image(final_images, "./output/results_page_{}.png".format(count), nrow=2*opt.num_variations+1, padding=2, range=(0, 1), pad_value=0.5, normalize=False)
```

In the server with CUDA 11.0 and PyTorch 1.7.1 py3.7_cuda11.0.221_cudnn8.0.5_0. The code is working well. And I can save RGBA format files.

However, when I run the code in CUDA 11.1 and PyTorch 1.9.1 py3.7_cuda11.1_cudnn8.0.5_0, It doesn't work, and the output is

```
The size of tensor a (3) must match the size of tensor b (4) at non-singleton dimension 0
```

.So I have to convert the segmentation mask to `convert("RGB")` and save the RBG image.

So, there is a difference between these two VERSION?

Comment: This has nothing to do with CUDA. I have edited your question accordingly

Comment: *"So, there is a difference between these two VERSION?"* -- I sure hope so. Otherwise, I upgraded my PyTorch for nothing.